# how to preserve layout of text in a TextArea control

Tags: asp.net, text, layout, textarea

Ho do I preserve the layout of text in a TextArea control in asp.net ?

e.g.

"This is some text:
     - line 1 text
     - line 2 text
     - line 3 text"

Comment: TextArea in what - html or flash or something else?

Comment: If you mean trying to put it out the text output from the textarea, try putting it in a <pre>...content from text area here...</pre>?

Answer (score 0):

asked this so i post the answer, as I couldnt find it anywhere else online...

You just need to prefix the text string with '@' and the text will retain its layout. e.g.: